# Run fabric script on cronjob

Tags: python, cron, fabric

Simple question but I cannot find the answer anywhere, all posts are about how to run cron inside a fabric script. But how can I run a fabric script on my crontab? Something like this:

```
00 00 * * * /project/folder/fab deploy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, this is my crontab to run a fabric script:

```
00 00 * * * cd /project/folder && fab deploy
```